# Webpack, exports & ES modules: ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm developing a particular npm package, where I want to be able to import various helpers from the base package in ESM syntax, e.g.,

```
import {
   myFunction,
   myConstant
} from 'my-npm-package-library'
```

This is my entrypoint index.ts file:

```
// Interface CelestiaSkyViewerOptions:
export interface CelestiaSkyViewerOptions {
  fullscreen?: boolean
  showSolar?: boolean
  showEcliptic?: boolean
  showAsterisms?: boolean
  showStars?: boolean
  showConstellations?: boolean
  showConstellationBoundaries?: boolean
  showCardinalPoints?: boolean
  showTimeAndCoordinateLocation?: boolean
  showAstronomicalTime?: boolean
  showCopyright?: boolean
}

// Export all default components:
export { default as CelestiaAstronomicalEpoch } from '@/components/CelestiaAstronomicalEpoch/CelestiaAstronomicalEpoch.vue'

export { default as CelestiaCopyright } from '@/components/CelestiaCopyright/CelestiaCopyright.vue'

export { default as CelestiaIAUStarKey } from '@/components/CelestiaIAUKeys/CelestiaIAUStarKey.vue'

export { default as CelestiaObserverLocale } from '@/components/CelestiaObserverLocale/CelestiaObserverLocale.vue'

export { default as CelestiaOrientationCompass } from '@/components/CelestiaOrientationCompass/CelestiaOrientationCompass.vue'

export { default as CelestiaOrientationPermission } from '@/components/CelestiaOrientationPermission/CelestiaOrientationPermission.vue'

export { default as CelestiaSkyViewer } from '@/components/CelestiaSkyViewer/CelestiaSkyViewer.vue'

export {
  annotateBody,
  drawBody,
  drawClosedPath,
  drawEllipticalGalaxy,
  drawLine,
  drawMoon,
  drawSun,
  drawText,
  highlightBody,
  resetPath
} from '@/composables/canvas'

export { azimuthalOffset } from '@/composables/celestia'

export { bayerStarsFilter, iauStarsFilter } from '@/composables/filters'

export {
  cardinals,
  coords,
  latitude,
  locatedAt,
  longitude,
  onEquatorialPositionChange,
  position,
  useObserversLocation,
  validateLatitude,
  validateLongitude
} from '@/composables/geolocation'

export { datetime } from '@/composables/globals'

export {
  deviceOrientationPermissionDialogOpen,
  deviceOrientationPermissionState,
  isOrientationCompassOpen,
  orientationCompassHeading,
  useDeviceMotionPermission,
  useDeviceOrientationPermission
} from '@/composables/orientation'
```

However, when attempting to commit this code, the on-commit linter I have is giving me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
```

I've been trying to Google around this particular error, but nothing seems to want to play ball with the linter...

Full stack trace for any garbage aficionados:

```
ERROR  ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
        This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/michael/observerly/celestia-vue/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/michael/observerly/celestia-vue/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a linter error (message) but rather a runtime error. Where exactly is that error thrown? Since none of the code you posted references `module` it's definitely not thrown there.

Comment: @FelixKling Hi Felix, thanks for your comment. It's being thrown when running npm run lint -> which in turn calls vue-cli-service lint... I'll add the full stacktrace of the error to the question.

Comment: @FelixKling I feel like this could be helpful: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#library

Comment: Or even webpack build targets?

Comment: It seems that removing `type: module` from my package.json has removed the error...